# Print filename from url

Tags: views

Im using Drupal 6 with Audio.

I have created a view that shows a list of files to download and play. There are two fields which both show the download link. I would like to change the second download link field so that it strips all the info and only prints the filename from the url contained in its content. So instead of

```
<*a href-"file/path/music20.mp3">Download <a*>
```

I would like to see

```
music20.mp3
```

or

```
music20
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you want `<a href-"file/path/music20.mp3">music20.mp3</a>` ?

Comment: ^? He means he only wants the file name shown. It has been a while since I used D6, But try looking at the options for the field. If it is a file field it may have an option to only show the file name, or you might have  to uncheck a checkbox for link to content.

Comment: Yes I want the filename shown. I am using Views to create that list and there are no options for filename for Audio items.

I was thinking that maybe there is a way of preprocessing via the template file and using php basename to pull the filename. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

In drupal 7, views 3 if you add a relationship **File Usage: File** you get some new fields you can add to your view, including the filename. The filename includes the extension (.doc, .pdf etc). But even with that you could theme the specific field with a template where you could easily use php to cut the .mp3 part.